# placeOrderAction does not set order with the default status according to configuration in magento2

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, order-status

I have created a new payment method.

In system configuration, I have set that the new order status as **Pending**, however, when I place the order, the new order is created in **Processing** status.

Here is my system.xml code.

```
   <system>
        <section id="payment">
            <group id="zipcodpayment" translate="label" sortOrder="2" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Custom Payment</label>
                <field id="active" translate="label comment" sortOrder="1" type="select" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Enable</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="title" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Title</label>
                </field>
                <field id="order_status" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" canRestore="1">
                    <label>New Order Status</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Sales\Model\Config\Source\Order\Status\NewStatus</source_model>
                </field>             
                <field id="allowspecific" translate="label" type="allowspecific" sortOrder="40" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Payment from Applicable Countries</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Payment\Model\Config\Source\Allspecificcountries</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="specificcountry" translate="label" type="multiselect" sortOrder="41" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Payment from Specific Countries</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Directory\Model\Config\Source\Country</source_model>
                    <can_be_empty>1</can_be_empty>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
```

**Please help.**

Comment: Need to add full code lines of your `system.xml` config.

Comment: I edited my code,could you please check it...

Comment: Your payment is offline or online payment?

Comment: its an offline payment method.

Comment: Try to find the status in `core_config_data` table: SELECT * FROM core_config_data a WHERE a.`path` LIKE '%payment/zipcodpayment/order_status%'

Comment: Status  is "pending" in core_config_data table.

Comment: Strange. Did you clear Magento Cache?

Comment: Yes I did..please tell me if this link can provide any information.
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5860

Comment: You can upload your module to Github? I will download and check.